# Python: Either measure bytes for x seconds or measure time for x amount of bytes

Tags: python, argparse

I need help. Im using argparsing and im trying to measure how much data that the system receives/sends either within a x amount of seconds or measure the time it takes to measure x bytes.

if I use -t (time, seconds) then the -n (num, byes) should not be invoked, they cannot it at the same time.

Could someone help me?

This is my code so far:

```
if args.time is not None:
    try:
        duration = int(args.time)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid time value. Please provide an integer value.")
        exit()

    print(f"Measuring for {duration} seconds...")
    while True:
        data = b'\x00' * BUFFER_SIZE
        if not data:
            break
        clientSocket.send(data)
        total_bytes += len(data)

        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        if float(elapsed_time) >= float(duration):
            print("hello4")
            break
elif args.time == None:
    while True:
        if args.num is not None:
            data = b'\x00' * int(checkNum(args.num))
        else:
            data = b'\x00' * BUFFER_SIZE
        if time.time() - start_time > time_duration:
            break
        clientSocket.send(data)
        total_bytes += len(data)
        break

clientSocket.close()

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
bandwidth = (total_bytes / elapsed_time) * 8 / 1000000
```

Comment: And what isn't working?  You can use `if not args.time == not args.num:` to detect that only one provided.  Then, it's just `if` and `else`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion. Let `parse_args()` treat an attempt to use both `-t` and `-n` as an error.

Comment: both if statements run no matter if i use -t or -n, i have used add_mutually_exclusive_group on them, so I dont have a problem with more than one being used, but I dont know if my code is done correctly, because even when i use -t, it "stops" after the "if float(elapsed_time) >= float(duration):"